# magento New Product Attribute not show any option in admin

Tags: php, magento, attributes

im using Magento (**Magento ver. 1.9.2.2**), i'm try to add **New Product Attribute** but it is not show any type of option or any thing in admin. i have did clear Cache Storage Management and Index Management but nothing change and i have try different web browser but issue is same.

[image]

**any help or suggestion will be appreciated**

Comment: Go to magento root folder-> Delete "Var" folder. Then reindex magento.

Comment: Can you share your demo url?

Comment: @stalinrajindian : yes i did , clear cache magento manually

Comment: @stalinrajindian : no its in my system

Comment: Please run below file in your root folder. magento check : https://gist.github.com/atomicpages/4383809